# General structure of classes suited for unittest

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

I'm working on a play app and want to improve my test coverage before going too far with the project. 
So far I have quite good test coverage on the model layer, but the controllers tend to get a lot of logic in them (accumulating stuff and calculating from the model results).

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to structure my application so that all parts are easily testable? I could of course refactor all the logic out of the controller and only have one call to a different class for each controller method and then only use the render methods in the controller, but it seems a bit drastic.

Is there a way I can look at the results after a method has been run in the controller, e.g

```
public static void controllerMethod(String a){
    String result = doSomething();
    String calcResult = calculateSomething(a);
    render(result, calcResult)
}
```

How can I test that after this method the expected result and calcResult is what I want it to be in a unittest?

All the examples on the play site is about testing the model layer. I know I can run Functional tests towards the controller, but that is a bit to shallow for what I want to test.

If you have any suggestions about how I can structure my classes in order to have an easily testable application, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know how you could do that... a test is always an external test wrapping the call to a function. You can't test partial results within the function itself. It's not debugging :(... The only thing I see for you is to unit-test each function using classical JUnit and then write a functional to test the whole controllerMethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers task should be (mostly) control of the flow of the application (which page to show next). For that you can use the [selenium tests](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/test#Seleniumtest) in Play.

If you find yourself adding a lot of login in the controller, either move it to methods in the related model (if applicable) or create a middle layer (ala Services) that manages the complex parts. They will be easier to test than Controllers, and will let you reuse the logic on several controllers (for example, acess via browser of REST API call)

Comment: This is actually what I was thinking about doing and is what I meant by moving the logic out of the controller and into other classes like a service layer. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

" How can I test that after this method the expected result and calcResult is what I want it to be in a unittest?" 
Don't run the JUnit test against controllerMethod(Sting a) but run two JUnit test against doSomething() and calculateSomething(a). As both return a String this is straight forward.

Edit. Also look into making a separate test project with the same package name as your "production" code as it makes it possible to test package scoped methods.

Comment: The problem with that is that those methods may be private and I don't want to expose them just to be able to test. Also I only want to test public methods in general.

Comment: Make your methods protected and then you can access them with JUnit provided they have the same package name.
There is also a way to test private methods just in cases like this. Look up testing thru reflection.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't like the approach of changing visibility in order to test. If things are hard to test you are usually doing something wrong. I think I will go for the proposal from Pere Villega and move what I can into the model classes and then the rest of the logic into a service layer. Then my controllers will be slim and all the code will be easily testable. Thanks for your replies